# Integral of a path using Taylor Expansion

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

I am following a book on Rough Paths (although Rough Paths are not relevant to this question) and would like to integrate the function of a path against that path. I have the following set up:

$X = (X^1,\cdots,X^d): [0,T] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$ is a path and $F:\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function. Also $s,t \in [0,T]$ such that $s < t$. We choose an arbitrary $u \in [s,t]$.

I would like to compute the following integral:

$$
\int^t_sF(X_u)dX_u.
$$

The book begins by Taylor expanding $F(X_u)$ and then integrating this expansion. This is how its written out in the book:
[image]

My issue comes with the first equality. If I do the Taylor expansion, I get

$$
F(X_u) = F(X_s) + DF(X_s)(X_u-X_s)+ \cdots 
$$

where $DF$ is the gradient of $F$. Then integrating both sides, I get

$$
\int^t_sF(X_u)dX_u = F(X_s)\int^t_sdX_u + DF(X_s)\int^t_s(X_u-X_s)\otimes dX_u+ \cdots 
$$
$$
\Leftrightarrow \int^t_sF(X_u)dX_u = F(X_s)(X_s-X_t)+ DF(X_s)\int^t_s(X_u-X_s)\otimes dX_u+ \cdots 
$$

My question is, how am I meant to recover the first equality in the proof in the book?

Many thanks

Comment: The first equality is trivial. It's simply because $F(x_s)(x_t-x_s) = \int_s^t F(x_s)\,dx_u$. The integrand doesn't depend on $u$.

Comment: @StefanPerko Yes sorry I should have clarified - my issues comes with the second term - the integral of F(X_u)-F(X_s)

Comment: The $-F(x_s)$ part is what my comment refers to. The $F(x_u)$ part is the LHS of the equation. They added in a zero. The equation can be read like $b = a + b - a$.

Comment: @StefanPerko oh right I see, this equality does not yet involve the taylor expansion. Its just simply rewritting the LHS by adding and subtracting f(X_s). Thank you very much. I am wondering then what the book means when it says "by a formal taylor expansion". I assumed that the proof would find the taylor expansion of f and then integrate, but this is clearly not the case.